# Mouse Over in whole Stage?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I want to run an Actionscript function when a user has his mouse in my flash stage.
Not in a specific button/image on the stage but just in the stage.
But when trying to use mouse over action on stage i get this message:
"This action requires an object to be selected on stage."

So, how can i use mouse over in the whole stage?

Answer (score 1):

In AS3 there's an event for when mouse leaves the stage so you could do something like this to get if the users mouse is in the stage.

```
var _mouseOnStage : Boolean = true;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_LEAVE, onMouseLeave);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);

function onMouseLeave(e:MouseEvent) : void {
    _mouseOnStage = false;
}

function onMouseMove(e:MouseEvent):void{
    _mouseOnStage = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have something that can be clicked, like some graphics drawing.

If you fill the stage with a rectangle of the same size, then add an event listener to the Stage, it should recognise it.

Comment: Well ... I tried adding a rectangle in a layer that was "as big" as the stage and used mouseover() event in this rectangle. The problem was that when other buttons were above this layer  and you move the mouse in these buttons(which were over the stage) mouseover() didn't work. It only worked when moving mouse over "empty spots" between the buttons that were above the rectangle

Comment: Ok, that's because the Stage layer is above the buttons in the Display List, and is over-riding their event listener. You should make sure the buttons are higher in the Display List by using the addChildAt(button, 0); method call. Are you adding the buttons as children of the background rectangle? If you posted some code, that would be very useful.

Comment: Um yeah I thought I was wrong with all this after writing it.. Ignore me.