# AS3 Clicking through the hidden Mask area

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am trying to create a Flash Application similar to [www.faceinhole.com](http://www.faceinhole.com).
So far I was able to load my photo through Browse functionality.
Display it inside a movie clip.
Mask this movie clip with an oval shape.
Add the transform controls (senocular) to resize and move the image.

The problem:
Whenever I click on the visible part of the Masked Movie Clip, I can successfully drag my photo around. However when I click on the hidden part of the Masked Movie Clip, I cannot drag my photo around.

Question: Is there a way to add mouseEnabled=false to the hidden area of a mask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a invisible (alpha=0) Sprite on top of everything on the stage or visible section, including the picture and mask and have that drag around.  Add a callback to it that updates the picture's position underneath the mask based on the drag values.  You'll need to reset the invisible sprite so you can keep dragging the picture and also put limits to how far it can be dragged.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I thought of this but couldn't find the keywords to google how to do this. Can you point me out to some keywords to look for or to a tutorial?

Comment: Invisible button (but you don't want a button, just a plain sprite).  The concepts are the same, though.  Like I said, create a sprite the size of the stage and drag that around.  You're using the sprite to capture the mouse so it can work all across the screen.  Another way would be to use a mouse move event and only activate it when the mouse is clicked and deactivate when the mouse is released.  The only other thing you need to do in this case would be to have another event callback for release off stage.  Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679052/mouse-over-in-whole-stage

Comment: I did as you said, I now have an invisible sprite with same location and same width/height as my image.

The only challenge am facing is telling the image to do exactly as the sprite is doing (scale, move, etc..) just like a mirror...can you point me to a tutorial that teaches how to do that?